# Standard way to import data to HANA

Tags: hana

We're building an application that could generate data for HANA to consume.

We can consider provide a REST API to export data by hour. But this will not be realtime.
Or we can provide a websocket API to return 'live' data.

So what is the best or standard way for HANA. What is the idea data format and how can HANA consume it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can create a web service on HANA and call this service from the source of data generator to pass new data to HANA.
This way the application will export its data at once to HANA